# What is the interface type of this LCD?

Tags: display, protocol

I'm trying to find out if this LCD uses eDP, or MIPI DSI, or something else so that I can choose a replacement LCD, and I'm a beginner at this.

[image]

I wasn't able to find it on the manufacturer's website, but noticed that they produce LCDs with different interfaces.

The FPC connector has 40 pins.

Comment: FPC 40 pin 0.5mm connector [compare](https://www.amazon.com/uxcell-Converter-Couple-Extend-Adapter/dp/B07RT6YCP4) with this product.

Comment: @Syed, I'm asking about the video interface: eDP, LVDS, MIPI DSI, etc.

Comment: Before I shut down the many browser windows, I wanted to record the info. [Contact](https://www.kingdisplay.net.cn/en/index.html) the manufacturer by email.

Comment: You can't understand what the interface is by just looking at the connector. It could be anything. If you measure a resistance of 100 Ohms across each pair then it could be MIPI DSI or LVDS as one covers the other. I'm seeing 6 pairs separated by ground lanes, so it could be LVDS with three pairs for EVEN (E0, E1, CLKE) and three pairs for ODD (O0, O1, CLKO). But, again, it could be anything.

Comment: @RohatKılıç, So connector type and signal interface are two different and independent things.

Comment: Exactly. A 40p connector can be used for LVDS, RGB, MIPI DSI or anything.

Comment: If your goal is to find a replacement LCD, just search for the reference, you'll find cheap replacement parts. Even if you could find the type of interface, most are not normalised: number of pins, order of the pins, number of channels, resolution, voltages, and so on can vary a lot.

Comment: @jcaron, You mean even if the signaling interface, panel size, resolution, and the connectors of two LCDs are the same they may not be interchangeable?

Comment: @apadana Indeed. Even within the same brand they may change pinouts from one model to another apparently similar one.

Comment: @jcaron, I have seen a few people replacing laptop LCDs successfully after only comparing panel size, resolution and connector type. Are laptop LCDs more "standardized" compared to tablet LCDs or those people were just lucky?

Answer (score 0):

It's *probably* 8-bit MIPI.  No guarantees though--so contact the manufacturer.

Go here: https://www.kingdisplay.net.cn/en/products.php?keyword=kd101&serachsub=&page=1

And notice that most of the 40-pin connectors in the same series are all 8-bit MIPI (although one is LVDS--so caveat emptor).